# Fastest way to search for a non-numeric value in CSV

Tags: bash, ksh

What's the fastest way in Linux/AIX- Unix using bash/ksh to get a non-numeric value in a particular column of a huge CSV file and the line number.

Let's say i have data in the following format,

```
1,AAA,486254452,1F
2,BAF,265363,6A
3,AFHGJ, ,3G
...
50000,GAJGFGS,.,5H
...
100000,GHFHFFS,47,6L
```

Considering the number of lines in the CSV could be easily 100,000 ,what's the fastest way to identify the line numbers which has non-numeric values in the 3rd column. Non-numeric must include - space,'.'.

I tried a shell script and looping thru each line of the file, but that takes a lot of time.

```
line=0
while read lineOfCSV
  3rdCol=`echo $lineOfCSV | cut -d ',' -f3`
  line=`expr $line +1`
  if ! [[ $3rdCol=~ '^[0-9]+$' ]] ; then
    echo "Line = :$line:  NON-NUMERIC VALUE :$3rdCol:"
  fi
done < data.csv
```

I ran the above code for a CSV file with 80000 lines, it took more than 10 minutes to process. So i stopped the script and googled for a faster solution. I couldn't found anything specific. So i have posted the question here.

Comment: Before accepting any valid answers from below, can you update  what was your original execution time and what factor of it was reduced from the most efficient solution below?

Comment: can you edit what non-numeric should contain. what is the it.. single quote and dot or both? '.'.

Comment: Post the original code please.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} $3 ~ /[^[:digit:]]/{print NR}' file
```

should do it.

As a side note this will bark for the punctuations and space in third column as well.

Comment: Adding the actual matching row along with the line number wouldn't hurt too  much? `{print NR,$0}` ?

Comment: @Inian : That is not in the requirement though.

Comment: Agreed, but would have made this a even more nicer solution! up-voted!

Comment: You don't even need any of the quantifiers: `$3 ~ /[^[:digit:]]/` will suffice

Comment: @glennjackman : Valid point.. Forgot I was dealing with regex match

Answer (score 3):

Perl is usually extremely fast for this kind of task:

```
perl -F, -ane '$F[2] =~ /\D/ and print "$.\n"' file
```

Comment: would be nice if you put a side note how this one is better than the other solution.

Comment: The OP is asking for "the fastest" way. This might be faster than awk.